# DART Web UI: How to reference index in iterate loop

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I would like to use the index of the iterate loop in the HTML as a value, as in:

```dart
   <select bind-value="gAddItem.drawType" 
            template iterate="int ind = 0; ind < gDrawDescs.length; ind++">
     <option value="{{ind.toString()}}"> {{gDrawDescs[ind]}} </option>
     </select>
```

But this intuitive syntax doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this in Dart Web-ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart doesn't seem to allow list range literals, which would allow the neat solution:

```dart
iterate="ind in [0 ... gDrawDescs.length]"
```

To get around this, create the following function:

```dart
List<int> createList(final int cnt) {
  var list = new List();
  for (var i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
     list.add(i);
  }
  return list;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```dart
iterate="ind in createList(gDrawDescs.length)"
```

Comment: This is close to as good as it gets. Dart's Web UI library doesn't expose the current index iteration variable, so you need to create your own range type function to do it. See this bug: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/277  If you agree this is something Web UI should do, you can leave a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Good news, everyone! The issue Seth Ladd linked to on Peter B's answer was [fixed](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/commit/9c79775383c4e01b2147e49de45ac70a82ff051b) a couple months ago, so now you can reference `{{$index}}` from inside a `<template>`. From the test code that was added in that commit:

```dart
Test the $index meta variable:
<template repeat="item in items" indentation="remove">
  <div>
    "{{item}}" is the {{$index}}{{suffix($index)}} item out of {{$list.length}}.
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or consider this

```dart
Iterable<int> Indices(int size) => Iterable<int>.generate(size, (i) => i);
```